# Как считать в массив текст из элементов, полученных при помощи getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript

Требуется считать в массив текст из элементов полученных при помощи `getElementsByClassName`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var mass = [];
   var ms1 = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
   for(var i = 0;i<ms1.length;i++){
    mass[i] = ms1[i].text();
   }
   console.log(mass);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="className">123</span>
 <span class="className">333</span>
 <span class="className">432</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var mass = [];
var ms1 = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
for (var i = 0; i < ms1.length; i++) {
  mass[i] = ms1[i].textContent;
}
console.log(mass);
```

```html
<span class="className">123</span>
<span class="className">333</span>
<span class="className">432</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Вижу, что `jQuery`, почему не на нем тогда все написать:

```
var arStr = [];
$('.className').each(function() {
     arStr.push($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: Не опытный) Все в одно гребу)